# Maps calculate best route between points

Tags: google-maps, path, coordinates

I have a list of points on map, let call a point - HUB.

I have about 100 Hubs and I need to calculate best route based on distance. I know GPS coordinates of each HUB and I try to find a library than can convert from Lat/Long to distance and calculate best route when I know the start point and destination point.

Please recommend me a library or suggest best way to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a traveling salesman solver for example geweb tsp solver.